# Highcharts plotLines with multiple xAxis and yAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple `xAxis` and `yAxis`. I want to have multiple `plotLines` on the xAxis, but each plotLine doesn't stay on it's course. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgCQV/339/). Click on `All` to see what I mean.

The `plotLine` on the first axis goes to the second axis as well. How could I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution suggested in the [HighCharts issue tracker](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2855#issuecomment-38802538) which involves defining the related `xAxis` on each `yAxis`. So a plotline defined on a particular `xAxis` will use the top and height of the related `yAxis` to draw the plotline only in the correct area.

```
yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: 'OHLC'
    },
    height: 200,
    lineWidth: 2,
    xAxis: 0,
}, {
    title: {
        text: 'Volume'
    },
    top: 300,
    height: 100,
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2,
    xAxis: 1,
}, {
    title: {
        text: 'Other data panel'
    },
    top: 300,
    height: 100,
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2,
    opposite: true,
    xAxis: 1,
}]
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/hxLp6zkg/) with each plotline only on its corresponding pane.

Note that the ability to define related axes appears to be undocumented in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis).

Comment: Wow, it's crazy. Good to know!